# Codeigniter Reservation Function - Limit Reservations to 1 Hour a Day

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

so I have a reservation function wherein users can book reservations for basketball courts each day. What I want is a validation for them to limit their bookings to one hour per day. What I initially came up with was to search all reservations in the database where the username of the one who made the reservation is the same with the session username. If the number of rows exceed or is equal to 1, then it should return false. The problem with this is that it will limit the reservation, but it will also limit the reservation for the other dates. What I want is that if I reserve for example today, I cannot reserve anymore on this day, but I can reserve tomorrow. What is the proper logic of implementing this?

[image]

[image]

Model:

```
function check_maxhour_courtone()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('courtone_reservation')->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'))->where('reservation_status', 1)->get();

    if($query->num_rows() >= 1)
    {
        return FALSE;  
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not really familiar with CI, I would conditionally check on the reservation_date if it matches today. If that is the case, you can check if a reservation is already made, if not then you can make the reservation.

Comment: You need to limit the reservations for every hour or 1 per day?

Comment: I need to limit reservations for each person for 1 hour per day. This means that for example, February 23, I reserved a slot for 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM, then I cannot reserve anymore a slot for 7:00 PM - 8:00 PM. However, I can still reserve another reservation for February 24, but should also allow only 1 hour worth of reservation for that day.

Comment: If i reserve from 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM on February 23 can i reserve again from 9:00 PM - 10:00 PM on February 23?

Comment: No, because I used up 1 hour already (6:00 PM - 7:00 PM). I can still reserve on February 24 though but will also have the same constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the reservation date and reservation time in separate columns I would pass the date to your function and check if they have a reservation on that date:-

```
function check_maxhour_courtone($desired_date = 0)
{        
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('courtone_reservation')->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'))->where('reservation_status', 1)->where('reservation_date', $desired_date)->get();

    if($query->num_rows() >= 1)
    {
        return FALSE;  
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

As an aside, you can put all of your `where` statements into a single array for easier readability:-

```
$where = array(
    'username' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
    'reservation_status' => 1,
    'reservation_date' => $desired_date,
);

$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('courtone_reservation')->where($where)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

1st tip. You need to pass the username variable in your function rather using straight the session. In that way you can control and check for any conditions you need.

Also you need to pass the reservation date to your function like below

```
    function check_maxhour_courtone($username, $date)
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')
                 ->from('courtone_reservation')
                 ->where('username', $username)
                 ->where('reservation_status', 1)
                 ->where('reservation_date',$date)
                 ->get();

        if($query->num_rows() >= 1)
            return FALSE;  
        return TRUE;
    }
```